# How can I output a code from a word I enter in a text field

Tags: flutter, encryption, textfield

What I do is export an encoding as required. My code has a bit of a problem that is difficult to solve, so I hope you can help.

here is my code:

```
String codecVal(String val) {
  switch (val) {
    case 'a':
      return '19';
    case 'b':
      return '00';
    case 'anh':
      return '70'; // here is the problem, it only returns 19 not 70
    default:
      return "";
  }
}

String someFunc(String val) {
  String textLetter = val;
  final textToList = textLetter.split('');
  // textToList.sort(); //if you need to sorted number uncomment this line
  final result = textToList.map((e) => codecVal(e)).toList();
  return result.join("-");
}
return Column(
  children: [
    _buildTextEditingDeltaViewCode(someFunc(textCodeElec.toLowerCase())),
    const SizedBox(height: 10),
  ],
);
```

Here is a picture of the project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is in `split method`  always will split String to single char**

```
     String textLetter="a anh b";
     final textToList = textLetter.split('');
    //this line will return  ["a", "n", "h"," "  , "a"," " ,"b"];
    //always will split String to single char

    //  try the following 
     final textToList = textLetter.split(' ');
```

You can read more about `split method` in this link [split method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.1/dart-core/String/split.html)

Comment: If I do it this way, I can't export single characters anymore. Is there any other solution? Please help me.